# "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error when deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, crud

I am executing a delete function in MVC 5 CRUD.

This is my code for my delete when it is confirmed:

```
  [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteFaculty")]
        public ActionResult DeleteFacultyConfirmed(int id = 0)
        {

            CS.Models.faculty fac = db.faculties.Find(id);
            foreach (var sched in fac.schedentries)
            {
                fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);
            }
            db.faculties.Remove(fac);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("DeletedFaculty", "Home");
        }
```

Here is the class of what I AM GOING TO DELETE COMPLETELY

```
public class faculty
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int faculty_id { get; set; }
    public string faculty_name { get; set; }

    public string faculty_lname { get; set; }

    public string faculty_email { get; set; }

    public string faculty_password { get; set; }

    public string faculty_dept { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<sched> schedentries { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the class where the one I am going to delete completely is a foreign key to:

```
public class sched
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int sched_id { get; set; }
    public string sched_day { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan sched_stime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan sched_etime { get; set; }

    public int faculty_id { get; set; }

    public virtual faculty faculty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my data context:

```
 public class CSdbConnectionString : DbContext
    {
        public CSdbConnectionString()
        : base("CSdbConnectionString")
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<sched>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.faculty)
            .WithMany(b => b.schedentries)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);           
        }

    public DbSet<appointment> appointments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<faculty> faculties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sched> scheds { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student> students { get; set; }

    }
```

So all in all, what I want to happen is that is to delete the data inside the faculty class and together with it to be delete is the data it has in the sched class.

I have researched and I've asked before that this is called cascading, and I found a solution here and that is what I copied.

Also, this line:

> fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);

should be

> db.schedentries.Remove(sched);

but I can't access the schedentries using the db. I don't know if that has something to do with the error.

Can someone help me?  Please enlighten me and don't go rough on me. I am very new in MVC and all help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting items from a collection inside a `foreach` loop that are enumerating the collection. To solve your problem you need to modify your code:

```
var itemsToRemove = fac.schedentries.ToList();
foreach (var sched in itemsToRemove)
{
    fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);
}
```

Instead of modifying the `fac.schedentries` collection while enumerating it a copy is created that is then enumerated.

When you use a `foreach` loop you have an enumerator (the `sched` variable) and this enumerator has to keep track of the current position within the collection (it keeps a link back to the collection being enumerated). If the collection is modified the enumerator is no longer able to keep track of this position and throws an exception to signal that.

Comment: @MigsZuniga That's a completely different issue from the original question (and actually in a completely different domain). Please spend some time investigating that error, and if you're still stuck, post a *new* question. Martin's solution perfectly solves your original question.

Comment: @MigsZuniga: That is a different problem related to your EF model. You should ask a new question about that problem. Or preferably just search Stack Overflow for the answer because I'm sure it is there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change

```
foreach (var sched in fac.schedentries)
{
    fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);
}
```

To

```
foreach (var sched in fac.schedentries.ToList())
{
    fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);
}
```

The `ToList()` will give you a new collection, and thus `fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);` will not modify the collection being iterated

Comment: did that but nothing happened sir, it still has the error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove items from the enumerables while enumeration is in progress. So this code will not work.

```
   foreach (var sched in fac.schedentries)
   {
        fac.schedentries.Remove(sched);
   }
```

replace it with

```
  fac.schedentries.RemoveAll(s => s != null);
```

Comment: If `schedentries` was already a list, `fac.schedentries.RemoveAll()` would be a very clean solution (as per my original comment). However, calling `.ToList().RemoveAll()` creates a new list, and then empties it - it doesn't empty the original collection (it will, in effect, do nothing).

Comment: My intellisense doesn't seem to find the RemoveAll